# PHPUnit can't find my classes but autoload in composer.json looks fine

Tags: composer-php, phpunit, phpstorm

I have the following in my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Athena\\Core\\": "core",
        "Athena\\Tests\\": "tests",
    }
}
```

And I have this directory structure:

```
core/
    Framework/
        Console/
            Commands/
                AbstractCommand.php
tests/
    Console/
        Commands/
            AbstractCommandTest.php
```

And when running my tests in PHPStorm, I get:
Error: Class 'Athena\Core\Framework\Console\Commands\AbstractCommand' not found

I thought maybe the vendor/autoload.php was not being loaded, but if I try to run `phpunit tests --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php`, I get errors saying can't declare already declared stuff so obviously it's already loaded.

What's going on? :S

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, when running a globally installed phpunit, it loads the vendor/autoload from composers install location, not the project. Hence it fails to load any project class files.